# Problems Iterating through a list of SQL tables with python

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

I am trying to iterate through tables in a mssql database using a python((3.5)pymssql)  script I am using the following,after connecting:

```
table = ("Accounts")  
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM %s",table)

if %s is replaced by a string, say 'Accounts' it works,

cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Accounts")
```

when I use table it fails with the following error:

> _mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near
>   'Accounts'.DB-Lib error message 20018

pymssql shows

```
cursor.execute("select 'hello' where 1 =%d", 1) as correct
```

Please help if you can, I am somewhat confused by what should be a simple problem.

Best Regards Richard C

Answer (score 0):

Looks like python creates parameters, so this should work

```
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(".", "sa", "password", "AdventureWorks2014")
cursor = conn.cursor()

table = ("AWBuildVersion")  
cursor.execute("declare @stmt nvarchar(400);set @stmt = 'select top 1 * from ' + %s;exec sp_executesql @stmt", table)

row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print("ID=%d, Name=%s" % (row[0], row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

conn.close()
```